# scan a string with empty space within loop in c and create a perfect table

Tags: c, string, loops

When I input the device name with empty space it will exit. I've tried to change it to fget then when the next loop it will skip "enter the device name. I also tried the "%[^\n]s" it also does the same thing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct deviceType
{
    char cName[20];
    float fPrice;
    int iQty;
    float fTotal;
};
void fnKeyIn(float*,int*);
float fnCalcTotal(const float,int);
void fnGetDiscount (const float,double*);
float fnAfterDiscount(const float,double);
void fnPrint(struct deviceType ,double,const float);

int main()
{
    struct deviceType asEntertaiment[50] ;
    char ans;
    int n,i=0;
    double afDiscount[i];
    float afAfterDiscount[i];
    float full = 0;

    do{
        printf("\nEnter device name: ");
        //gets(asEntertaiment[i].cName);
        scanf("%s",asEntertaiment[i].cName);
        getchar();

        fnKeyIn(&asEntertaiment[i].fPrice,&asEntertaiment[i].iQty);

        printf("\nDo you want to add more?\n");scanf("%s",&ans);

        i++;n=i;

    }while((ans=='Y')||(ans=='y'));

  printf("\nDevices         Price  Quantity  Total  Discount After Discount\n");

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            asEntertaiment[i].fTotal = fnCalcTotal(asEntertaiment[i].fPrice,asEntertaiment[i].iQty);

            if(asEntertaiment[i].iQty>=50)
                {
                    fnGetDiscount (asEntertaiment[i].fTotal,&afDiscount[i]);
                }
            else
                {
                    afDiscount[i]= 0;
                }

            afAfterDiscount[i] = fnAfterDiscount(asEntertaiment[i].fTotal,afDiscount[i]);
            full=full + afAfterDiscount[i];
            fnPrint(asEntertaiment[i],afDiscount[i],afAfterDiscount[i]);

        }

    printf("\nTotal amount payable: %3.2f",full);

    return 0;
}
    void fnKeyIn(float *price,int *quantity)
        {
            printf("\nEnter device price: RM ");
            scanf("%f",price);

            printf("\nEnter quantity ordered: ");
            scanf("%d",quantity);
        }
    float fnCalcTotal(const float Price,int Qty)
        {
            return(Price*Qty);
        }
    void fnGetDiscount (const float Total,double *Discount)
        {
            *Discount=Total*0.1;
        }
    float fnAfterDiscount(const float Total,double Discount)
        {
            return(Total-Discount);
        }
    void fnPrint(struct deviceType E,double Discount,const float After)
        {
            printf("\n%s %3.2f    %d      %3.2f   %3.2lf       %3.2f    ",E.cName,E.fPrice,E.iQty,E.fTotal,Discount,After);
        }
```

Comment: Use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read a whole line. Remember that [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) writes the ending newline to the buffer.

Comment: i already try fgets. When the next loop it will skip the enter device name.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i insert the picture of the output when i insert fgets

Comment: The arrays `afDiscount` and `afAfterDiscount` are zero sized. I guess it is not what you want. Also `ans` is a single char ; it may corrupt memory if you use it as a string because of the trailing '\0'. That apart, I can't reproduce (or don't understand) your problem.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text editors or text terminals. Post text.

Comment: okay sorry @n.m . already delete thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf()` function leaves any characters it did not want in the input stream, which in your case means that any characters entered by the user after the first word are still in the input stream. You can discard these characters like this:

```
printf("\nEnter device name: ");
//gets(asEntertaiment[i].cName);
scanf("%s",asEntertaiment[i].cName);
while (getchar() != '\n')
    continue;              // discard extra characters
```

If you really want to cover your bases, you can instead do:

```
int ch;
while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
    continue;
```

You have to use `int`, or a signed integer type, if you are going to test for `EOF`: `char`s are unsigned.

To get an input of multiple words, try using `fgets()` to read the characters up to the first newline, or a maximum number of characters, whichever comes first:

```
printf("\nEnter device name: ");
//gets(asEntertaiment[i].cName);
fgets(asEntertaiment[i].cName, 50, stdin);
int find = 0;
while (find < 49 && (asEntertaiment[i].cName)[find] != '\n')
    ++find;
if (find == 49) {
    while (getchar() != '\n')
        continue;              // discard extra characters
    }
(asEntertaiment[i].cName)[find] = '\0';
```

You still need to clear the input stream of extra characters if the user types in a device name that is longer than 49 characters (49 characters + '\0'). Those extra characters are still in the input stream after the call to `fgets()`. This will work as-is, but it would be better to write a function to handle this input and the cleaning up to invoke whenever you need it.

You should remember that some input functions leave characters behind in the input stream that are just waiting for the next input function if you don't clean up after them. Also, you should really validate your input. If the user enters a string instead of a number at the "Enter device price:" prompt, your program goes crazy. `scanf()` returns an `int` that is the number of successful assignments. So, if you ask for an `int`, and the user enters a string, the return value is 0. You can use this to test the user's input, and loop to get them to input again if the input is incorrect.

Comment: thank you @David Bowling . i try your method. but it output only the first word. how to make it output all the words. sorry i am new in this.

Comment: I misunderstood-- I thought that you only wanted the first word. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you.i've got it :)